# Stating constant values using '||'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, constants

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I am developing a plugin. I would like to know if it "right" to state a constant value like this (note the `||`):

```
CONSTANT_NAME ||= "Constant_value"
```

Is it a proper\ensured approach the above?

*P.S.*: I would like to make that in order to avoid to log warning messages like the following in the Apache `error_log` file:

```
/<RAILS_ROOT>/vendor/plugins/sample_plugin/lib/sample.rb:52: warning: already initialized constant CONSTANT_NAME
```

Comment: have a look at ruby memoization or check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696338/when-to-use-memoization-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @Octopus-Paul - I read this article http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2008/7/16/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-memoization where the author write memoization about methods... is it possible to use memoization with constant values?

Comment: Where do you assign that constant? Why is that code executing more than once?

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović It is because I am implementing an "acts_as_something" plugin and many my models are assigned to "acts_as_something".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems clumsy to define constants in several places. I even don't see why you need this. A better solution could be provided if you give more context.

Anyway, a trick could be to create a constant as a `Hash`. Then anywhere in you app you can define/redefine the it's content. Something like:

```
CONFIG = { :foo => "bar" }
```

Then anywhere else:

```
CONFIG[:foo] ||= baz
```

---

Edit:

With your gem context provided, I'd say you'd better avoid to include the constant at the model level: you won't have to worry if many models use it.

Define it at the application level inside your main `acts_as_something.rb` file for instance.

Comment: I need that because I am implementing an "acts_as_something" plugin and many my models are assigned to "acts_as_something".

Comment: why don't you define your constant at the app level instead of model level?

Comment: It is because those constants are related specifically to the plugin.

Comment: I know that, but you can define your constant at a higher level in your gem.

Comment: No, I can not state those constant values at the higher level since my plugin include a lot of modules... however, going back to the original question, is it save to use '||' to state constant values?

Comment: @Backo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2191/discussion-between-apneadiving-and-backo)